# Why does onclick listener give different output?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, dom-events

Here's a nut I'm just not able to crack. Consider the following HTML body:

```
<body onload="console.debug(document.documentElement);">
    <a href="#" onclick="console.debug(document.documentElement);">Click me</a>
</body>
```

The output of the first debug statement and the output of the second one, which fires when you click the link, differs in the Inspector console on Safari. After clicking the link, the two outputs look like this:

```
> HTMLHtmlElement
> <html>...</html>
```

Both are expandable, but the first one seems more like a proper DOM element with all its nuts and bolts (prototype, event listeners, child and parent relations, etc), while the second one only displays the element and its children as HTML.

There is no difference between the output given in the Firebug console in Firefox, where each output only links to the HTML inspector.

Comment: Well obviously the first script is run inline, before the document is completely parsed.  Perhaps `HTMLHtmlElement` is a placeholder object that Safari uses before it's finished building the DOM?

Comment: The bug (if it is one) also happens in Chrome, but corrects itself when reopening the console.

Comment: [Chrome latest dev]. Actually if you refresh the page with this sometimes you'll get HTMLHtmlElement other times you'll get markup.

Comment: Does it differ if you use a button instead of an <a> tag

Comment: Philip: If I remember correctly, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in safari, for both Firefox and IE9 give the same output.

If it really bugs you you can report a bug: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Or it is a difference in the engine.

Comment: If it also happens in Chrome, it's probably a "bug" in Webkit.  I doubt I'd call it a bug though, it's probably just an implementation detail of their parser.